# Best way to update multiple documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, updates, bulk, mongoimport

I am pretty new in MongoDB, we have the following requirement.

Currently we are using MySQL for all data analysis which is not scaling hence we are planning to use MongoDB for the same.

The initial performance looks very impressive. We are planning to maintain data in both MySQL and MongoDB for now. Only data which is required for analytics will be synced to Mongodb at reqular intervals.

We are using Mongoimport for one time syncing. Everytime there is new update to the data we need to sync the same to MongoDB.

The problem with mongoimport is that it overwrites the existing data.

```
Following is the sample data -

{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("566be4bf5506903ca147a985"), 
  "uid" : "1", 
  "attributes" : [ { 
      "Age" : "26", 
      "City" : "Bangalore", 
      "State" : "Karnataka", 
      "Gender" : "female"
  } ], 
  "sent" : [ { 
       "mid" : "7", "entered_date" : "150117" 
  }, { 
       "mid" : "8", "entered_date" : "150201"
  } ], 
  "opened" : [ { 
       "mid" : "15", "viewed_date" : "150222", "viewed_time" : "03000"
  } ] 
}
```

Now if we get 1,00,000 uid's whose attributes needs to be updated. What is the best way to achieve the same? We have tried Bulk.find.update() method provided by MongoDB. Is this the right approach or is there any better way to update specific fields like for example Age within Attributes etc in bulk.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yeah... Bulk Update fits this scenario. You get better throughout if you index the collection being updated. Apart from bulk update you can try partial update as well using $set operator as you are not updating the whole document. To check the performance of both, you can use explain() command with query planner and executionStats

Comment: I hope you know the indexing concept used by mongodb, If not look into that and index the uid field so that mongo can find more effectively..